# check date in multiple access columns and return

Tags: sql, date, ms-access-2010

I create an estimate and send it to the customer. If the customer has not responded in 3 days, I send a follow-up message. In 3 more days, another follow up message.

I store all of this information in an Access 2010 database. Records are created via an InfoPath form.

In the table, I have 4 columns of dates: GenDate, F1Date, F2Date, F3Date. On each record, GenDate is stamped with the date the record was created via an InfoPath form, so it is always filled in.

F1Date is only given a date when the record has been followed up on for the first time and is null otherwise. F2Date gets a date for the second follow up and is null otherwise. F3Date is used the same.

This is what I am working with so far:

```
SELECT Active.GenDate, Active.F1Date, Active.F2Date, Active.F3Date
FROM Active
WHERE (Active.GenDate <= DATE() - 3)
```

This returns the correct records if I only want to evaluate the GenDate column, but how do I also check the others and only return a record where each column is evaluated as being 3 or more days old?

Example:
Record 1:
    Today is 12/18, GenDate is 12/9, F1Date is 12/13, F2Date is 12/17, F3Date is null
Record 2:
    Today is 12/18, GenDate is 12/9, F1Date is 12/13, F2Date is null, F3Date is null
Record 3:
    Today is 12/18, GenDate is 12/12, F1Date is null, F2Date is null, F3Date is null

Result:
Record 2 & Record 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just `and` in the additional conditions while also comparing for `NULL` values:

```
SELECT a.GenDate, a.F1Date, a.F2Date, a.F3Date
FROM Active a
WHERE (a.GenDate <= DATE() - 3) and
      (a.F1Date <= DATE() - 3 or a.F1Date is NULL) and
      (a.F2Date <= DATE() - 3 or a.F2Date is NULL) and
      (a.F3Date <= DATE() - 3 or a.F3Date is NULL)
```